# How to fix the icon to be in right side?

Tags: react-native

icon need to be on the right side.

This is for a new component

```
<View style={{ borderBottomWidth: 0.4, borderBottomColor: '#858585' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={Style.suggestionView}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.UserStore.addRecentSearch(item[this.props.text_key])
            this.props.NavigationStore.navigate({ routeName: 'ProductInfo', params: { item } })
            this.autoCompleteTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
              if (mounted) this.setState({ showAutoComplete: false })
            }, 400)
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ marginLeft: 20, textAlign: 'left', color: '#9B999A', fontFamily: 'Poppins-bold' }}>{suggestion}</Text>
          <Icon name='chevron-right' size={20} style={{ color: 'grey' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

I expect the output will show the icon in right side.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the below code:

```
<View style={{ borderBottomWidth: 0.4, borderBottomColor: '#858585' }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={Style.suggestionView}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.UserStore.addRecentSearch(item[this.props.text_key])
                this.props.NavigationStore.navigate({ routeName: 'ProductInfo', params: { item } })
                this.autoCompleteTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                  if (mounted) this.setState({ showAutoComplete: false })
                }, 400)
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ marginLeft: 20, textAlign: 'left', color: '#9B999A', fontFamily: 'Poppins-bold' }}>{suggestion}</Text>
            <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
              <Icon name='chevron-right' size={20} style={{ color: 'grey' }} />
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

Comment: Did you give '100%' width and height to your TouchableOpacity ?

Comment: i fixed it with flex 1